# New created elements are not delegated listeners in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

When creating a new user via Ajax, a new user element (which is created manually) is not delegated events.

If I try to move on of my elements from one list to another an call `this.delegateEvents()` the click listeners are applied. However, no matter what I try I cannot get the click listeners to apply to this newly created element.

The event does not even need to be attached to the model, just a simple show/hide event is all I need it to do.

```
events: {
      'click a.toggle': 'toggleContent',
    },

addNewUserElement: function (userId) {
    var $formName = this.$('form').attr('name');
    var $listElement = this.createNewListElement(userId, $formName);
    this.trigger('user-created-event', $listElement); // this.onUserCreate
},

createNewListElement: function (userId, $formName){
    var html =  this.$('form input#' + $formName + '_lastName').val().toUpperCase()
    // more html creation
    return html;
}

onUserCreate: function ($el) {
   var targetList = '#active-users'
   alert("User created");
   this.insertIntoList(targetList, $el);
},

insertIntoList: function(targetList, $elementToMove){
        this.undelegateEvents();
        var added = false;
        var $targetList = // grab a set of <li>'s

        $targetList.append($elementToMove);

        this.delegateEvents();
        return false;
    },
```

Comment: Can you provide a simplified and preferably self-contained example of what you're doing? There's a lot of noise here that you need to remove, you can't expect people to wade through all that, maybe a functional demo on jsfiddle.net would help.

Comment: What does `createTargetListHandle` do?

Comment: @UziKilon oh sorry, I was cleaning up the code, it just returned some more HTML its not too relevant

Comment: I can't see in the code you pasted here, where you actually add a new element to the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having here was that I was creating a raw piece of HTML without attaching it to a Backbone model. It needed to be attached to a JS model and assigned all the relevant listeners manually. This is also why moving elements from one list to another did not create the same issue, as they were already attached to the other JS class.

In another part of the code, there was a createChildViews method, so I separated it out and passed the new piece of HTML through this method:

```
createChildViews: function () {
    var $els = this.$('#active-users li, #deactivated-users li');
    _.each($els, function (element) {
        this.createChildView(element);
    }, this);
},

createChildView: function(element){
    var user = new User({ // the other JS class
        el: element
    });
    this.listenTo(user, 'user-created-event', function (view) {
        this.onUserCreate(view);
    }, this);

},

onUserCreate: function ($el) {
    var targetList = '#active-users';
    window.alert("User created");
    this.createChildView($el);
    this.insertIntoList(targetList, $el);
},
```

This meant that all of the relevant listeners were attached to the HTML.